# jquery accordion - How to activate a panel based on active class inside the panel?

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

So I have a jquery accordion based off h2s and an unordered list. Inside the list, there is a list item that has an a href with active class associated with it.

Is there way to get the jquery accordion to fire the correct panel if it has an active class?

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

You will want to get the index of your active class and use the "active" option on the accordion.

```
function setActive() {
    var index = $('#myaccordion li').index($('#myaccordion li.activeClass'));
    $('#myaccordion').accordion("option","active" index);
}
```

For more information you can look [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
Hope this helps.